# Is there any bad connotation when we say one thing is cheaper than another?

Tags: word-usage

I'm aware that when we say things like:

> It's a cheap cell phone.
>
> That's a cheapo, throw it out.

It does mean something is clearly of bad quality. But how about when comparing things? for example:

> Those shoes are cheaper than these.
>
> That hotel is cheaper than this one.

Does it give the impression of lower quality, too? How subtle is it? Should I avoid it in any case?

Comment: It does have that connotation of being poor quality, at least to my ear. You can try *economical, low-priced, etc* instead.

Comment: It depends on the context. In _that hotel is cheaper than this one but offers the same accommodations_, using _cheaper_ doesn't carry any negative connotations. Usually, when people compare price, they also compare quality.  Your last two sentences are ambiguous. If someone said either to me, I would follow up with something along the lines of "but is X better?"

Comment: 'cheap' is different from 'cheaper'. 'That hotel is cheap' is definitely negative, almost pejorative, judgmental. 'That hotel is cheaper' just says that it is less expensive. There may be a tinge of inferred 'not as good' but is not a definite negative as 'cheap'.

Comment: Any person in sales, when selling a less expensive version of an item will prefer (and sometimes even redirect you) that their item is 'less expensive' than the competitor, not 'cheaper' because of the quality connotation in 'cheaper'.

Comment: Any time something costs less than something else, it's common to think, "Why does it cost less? It must not be as good in some way." So while the word *cheap* does add extra negative connotation over other words and phrases like "more affordable", there is always a good chance for a negative inference when pointing out a lower price, especially in comparison to another product (i.e., it might make the other product seem better). See also: [prestige pricing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prestige-pricing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Cheap** has two meanings.

Cheap is often used to convey **low quality**. It easily gets attached to any object being described, even if the price is not low at all.

*These cheap shoes cost half my paycheck!*

It can also mean **a price that is lower than expected**. In fact, the original meaning of cheap was 'bargain'.   To make sure it has this meaning, use the adjective to modify something related to the price and not the item itself.

*Look at the cheap price tag on these shoes!*

To illustrate, note how the meaning shifts in the following sentences:

*I bought a cheap laptop.*

*I bought a laptop for a cheap price.*

The 'low quality' connotation is minimized when 'cheap' becomes the comparative adjective, 'cheaper'.  It imparts some context that it is probably the price of two items you are comparing. However, because you are not stating clearly that it is the price that is cheap, it still conveys a the possibility of low quality.

Comment: I think your last example sums it up pretty nice. +1

Comment: I like the last example, but price tags, being made of cardboard, are usually cheap.

Comment: So funny, TimLymington!  I imagine some marketing types looking at the price tags in different stores in a mall, comparing the quality of the paper, the ink, the little plastic thing that attaches it.    But I think that illustrates it perfectly. Whatever noun the adjective 'cheap' modifies, is classed as 'low quality'.  If you apply it directly to the word 'price', all ambiguity is gone.

Comment: +1 but you might want to add (as per ChongDogMillionaire's and Mitch's comments to the question) that "cheaper" doesn't (necessarily) have the same negative connotation.

Comment: Thanks TripeHound! That's a really good point, and it more directly addresses the OP's question.

Comment: "Cheap price" sounds awkward to  me, and in fact this usage doesn't match any of the senses defined in [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cheap). A "cheap price" would be _a price_ which you didn't have to pay much to get — perhaps if you are somehow bidding on futures for prices, or something. Instead, you could use "low price", or "bargain price".

Comment: I agree with you mattdm, it's an awkward usage in writing, and I appreciate your rigorous example of bidding on futures.  But 'cheap price' is in common conversational use, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 5):

I know you've already accepted an answer but I would still like to offer what little wisdom I have.

Context is definitely huge when dealing with the word **cheap**

In order to illustrate this, please see the examples below:

---

> Guy1: Should we fly directly to Miami?
>
> Guy2: Nah, let's catch the flight to West Palm and drive down; the flight is much **cheaper**.
>
> Guy1: Cool, which hotel should we get.
>
> Guy2: Whichever one is **cheaper**, but not too **cheap**.

---

You are in a store and you overhear:

> Wow, these shoes are **cheap**.

versus

> Wow! These shoes are **cheap**!

versus

> Wow! These shoes are **inexpensive**!

---

> Husband: Which water heater should we buy to replace the old one?
>
> Wife: I'd say this one; it is much more **affordable**.
>
> Husband: No way! Haven't you heard of how **cheap** that brand is?! We'll pay the extra $100 and save ourselves a headache.

---

You invite your friend to the baseball game this weekend and they say:

> I'd love to but only if we get **cheap-seats**.

versus

> I'd love to but I can only get **budget-friendly** seats.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, avoid it, preferably. My mother tongue is not English, but I have been told by a British person that - at least to him - "cheaper" did have a negative connotation. After all, English is spoken by hundreds of millions of people, and not all speakers get the same meaning from the same words, so even when somebody feels no negative flavour in a word, chances are that somebody else feels it. So, when you mean "less expensive", just say "less expensive": this doesn't lend itself to confusion.

Comment: You are quite right. But it is possible, in the right context, to use *cheap* without it necessarily implying poor quality - though often it does. Also a *cheap comment* or *cheap remark* is something easily made but at the expense of another person's feeling or reputation.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't necessarily give the impression of lower quality. It really refers to the price. Some X shoes might cost 100$ and some Y shoes cost 80$. If the X shoes are on sale and drop the price to 70$, that doesn't mean that the quality is lower than that of the Y shoes that cost 10$ more.

But it might actually imply that the cheaper shoes are not as good as the expensive ones. Really depends on the context; I don't think there is a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't even feel like the two senses in which it describes a product are different denotatively. They might be listed as two definitions provided in a dictionary but if you look at them they mean the same thing: inexpensive.

The thing is that while the adjective technically modifies one noun, what you're actually describing is something else that's closely related to it.

*Look at these great shoes I bought. They were cheap too!*

What you're actually describing is the *price tag* on the shoes. The shoes are the same regardless of the price tag.

*I bought these last month and they're already falling apart! What cheap shoes!*

Here, what you're describing is the *manufacturing* of the shoes. It was low-cost, inexpensive (in other words, cheap) manufacturing. The low *quality* of the shoes has allowed you to infer that the manufacturing was cheap.

If you call a *person* cheap, it's again the same denotative meaning, but again is applied to something else that's closely related to the person--the kinds of products they buy.

But there's also a different sense that is similar but not quite the same, when you're discussing *effort* rather than *resources*. Examples are as in *cheap tactics* or *taking cheap shots*.

Generally there's no expense monetarily but it's still similar in that what's being described produces results for little effort.

Comment: A 'cheap remark' could not be called an inexpensive one. And most, if not all, dictionaries list two senses and thus two denotations.

Comment: I do like this answer though. If it the author would fix it up a little, it'd have my up-vote :)

Comment: True enough. Edited to mention that sense.